# Run a script after I unlock my Windows session?

Tags: scripting, accounts, session, windows

How do I run a script each time I unlock my Windows 7 session?

So, if I lock my session and then log in again, I want the script to run.

Do login scripts configured in the Group Policy do this or will they only work the first time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scheduled Tasks is what you need. You can set a trigger for both workstation lock and workstation unlock. If you need to deploy it out to more machines, use SCHTASKS.EXE (provided with windows).

Hope that helps

Comment: Cool. I didn't even know that was an option in Windows 7. It used to be you had to write a winlogon notification app and register it with the system to be triggered on shell change between the desktop and the lock screen.

Comment: +1 - For someone just getting ready to roll out Win 7 that's real handy to know.

Comment: BoxerBucks: Will you release the source for that?

Answer (score 0):

Group Policy login scripts only process when you first logon. If you only reboot once a month and just keep locking/unlocking, login scripts will run once a month for you.

Comment: but task scheduler can run tasks every computer unlock